# Slideshow working in every browser but chrome, even works in chrome incognito

Tags: jquery

I have recently added a jquery gallery to my page, it works in every single browser except for some instances of google chrome (doesnt work on my computers, yet works on my co workers). It even works perfectly in incognito mode in chrome. I am very perplexed by this issue, im assuming its an issue with how google handles the cache or perhaps im running an extra instance of jquery that i havent noticed.
[image: SCREENSHOT]

```
<script language="javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){
var a = function(self){
self.anchor.colorbox();
};
$("#pikame").PikaChoose({buildFinished:a,carousel:true,carouselOptions:{wrap:'circular'}});

});

        </script>
```

EDIT: forgot the link http://ra-yon.com/beta/Test_sites/HFE/advertisements.php

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this issue was caused by a chrome extension -adblock
I had my images and js in a folder called advertisement, which was black listed by the program and this didnt allow anything to load properly.
changed the name of the folder and now everything works great!